# Why does jax.numpy.dot() run slower than numpy.dot() on CPU?

Tags: python, numpy

I want to use JAX to accelerate my numpy code on CPU, later on GPU. Here is my example code running on my local computer (only CPU):

```
import jax.numpy as jnp
from jax import random, jix
import numpy as np
import time

size = 3000

key = random.PRNGKey(0)
x =  random.normal(key, (size,size), dtype=jnp.float64)

start=time.time()
test = jnp.dot(x, x.T).block_until_ready()
print('Time of jnp: {}s'.format(time.time() - start))

x2=np.random.normal((size,size))

start=time.time()
test2 = np.dot(x2, x2.T)
print('Time of np: {}s'.format(time.time() - start))
```

I got a warning and the time costs are as follows:

```
/.../lib/python3.7/site-packages/jax/lib/xla_bridge.py:130: 
UserWarning: No GPU/TPU found, falling back to CPU.
warnings.warn('No GPU/TPU found, falling back to CPU.')
Time: 0.45157814025878906s
Time: 0.005244255065917969s
```

Did I do anything wrong here? Should JAX also accelerate numpy code on CPUs?

Comment: Chances are high, that numpy is using (Open-)[BLAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_Linear_Algebra_Subprograms) and there is not much to optimize for `np.dot()`.

Comment: @sascha But it does not make sense that JAX is much slower than NumPy. I have not figure out the reason yet.

Comment: This does not surprise me. Dot (vector or matmul; does not matter) is completely hand-coded for every kind of cpu-arch and you won't beat this with automatic-compilers. Without much knowledge about JAX, it's probably about scheduling, optimizing temporaries and some other stuff -> resulting in great code when multiple "kernels" are *fused*. But *dot* is so elemental, that there is no chance to reach it. Additional remark: i mentioned openblas: but in some dists, Intels MKL is used: do you expect some automatic compilers to beat hand-coded matmul code (by intel-devs) on your (maybe) intel cpu?

Comment: Also read: [this](https://github.com/google/jax/issues/3832#issuecomment-663580284)

Comment: Perhaps numpy is also much faster because the shape of `x` is `(3000, 3000)` and the shape of `x2` is `(2,)` :)

Comment: @jakub You found it! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are probably performance differences between Jax and Numpy, but in the original post, the time differences mostly come down to a mistake in the array creation. The array used by Jax has the shape 3000x3000, whereas the array used by Numpy is a 1D array with length 2. The first argument to [`numpy.random.normal`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.normal.html) is `loc` (i.e., the mean of the Gaussian from which to sample). The keyword argument `size=` should be used to indicate the shape of the array.

```
numpy.random.normal(loc=0.0, scale=1.0, size=None)
```

Once this change is made, the performance between Jax and Numpy is less different.

```
import time
import jax
import jax.numpy as jnp
import numpy as np

size = 3000

key = jax.random.PRNGKey(0)
x = jax.random.normal(key, (size, size), dtype=jnp.float64)

start = time.time()
test = jnp.dot(x, x.T).block_until_ready()
print("Time of jnp: {:0.4f} s".format(time.time() - start))

x2 = np.random.normal(size=(size, size)).astype(np.float64)

start = time.time()
test2 = np.dot(x2, x2.T)
print("Time of np: {:0.4f} s".format(time.time() - start))
```

The output of one run is

```
Time of jnp: 2.3315 s
Time of np: 2.8811 s
```

---

When measuring timed performance, one should collect multiple runs because a function's performance is a spread of times instead of a single value. This can be done with the Python standard library [`timeit.timeit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html#timeit.timeit) function or the [`%timeit`](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-time) magic in IPython and Jupyter Notebook.

```
import time
import jax
import jax.numpy as jnp
import numpy as np

size = 3000

key = jax.random.PRNGKey(0)
xjnp = jax.random.normal(key, shape=(size, size), dtype=jnp.float64)
xnp = np.random.normal(size=(size, size)).astype(np.float64)

%timeit jnp.dot(xjnp, xjnp.T).block_until_ready()
# 2.03 s ± 39.4 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit np.dot(xnp, xnp.T)
# 3.41 s ± 501 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

xjnp = xjnp.astype(jnp.float32)
xnp = xnp.astype(np.float32)

%timeit jnp.dot(xjnp, xjnp.T).block_until_ready()
# 2.05 s ± 74.3 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit np.dot(xnp, xnp.T)
# 1.73 s ± 383 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

It seems like there is an optimized dot operation for 32-bit floats in Numpy.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The only thing that I found differently is the time performance. On my laptop (8 cores), numpy.dot takes 0.3176 s to run the code (dtype = float64), which is faster than jax.numpy.dot (0.4529 s). If I change the dtype to float32, numpy.dot is even faster, which only takes 0.2112 s, but jax.numpy.dot still takes 0.4537 s.